# Iterator and/or iterable difference and similarites?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

Can someone please explain the difference between an iterator and a iterable?

Furthermore, if is it a good practice to have a class that defines the dunder methods `__iter__` and `__next__` at the same time?

```
    class MyIter:
        def __init__(self, n):
            self.n = n

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def __next__(self):
            self.n /= 2
            if self.n < 1:
                raise StopIteration
            return self.n
```

Comment: The best solution to _which_ problem exactly ? All your example are the expected behaviour.

Comment: A have a big class and I use iterators several times so actually None of the above really work for me

Comment: Why should an iterator reset itself once it gets to the end? The iterator itself can't tell the difference between it being consumed by `list(x)` (where you appear to want it to reset) and `for i in x:`) (where reset itself would produce an infinite loop).

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the difference between iterators and iterables. Maybe you learned from one of those terrible tutorials where they make an object iterable by turning it into its own iterator. If you want to eat cakes repeatedly, you don't buy a reusable cake; you need a *source* of cakes, like a bakery, which is not itself a cake. If you want to iterate repeatedly, you don't need a reusable iterator; you need a *source* of iterators, which is not itself an iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only implement `__next__` if you want your instances to act like generators, and thus be exhaustible. Here, what you want is `MyIter.__iter__` to return a generator, otherwise anything altering the instance will affect the iteration.

```
class MyIter:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        n = self.n
        while n >= 1:
            yield n
            n /= 2

obj = MyIter(10)
list(obj) # [10, 5.0, 2.5, 1.25]
list(obj) # [10, 5.0, 2.5, 1.25]
```

Also note that it is not a problem that a class instance with `__next__` be exhaustible. It is actually what makes classes such `itertools.product` so useful.